# gauge.js - Can't get to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement http://bernii.github.com/gauge.js/ using the gauge.min.js not coffee.
But for the life of me I cannot get this to even show. Could anyone give me the code to make this show up? Like write the html doc, then I can edit it and place in my work. please any help would be great. Bit of noob here.
Thanks

If anyone could make the doc and link to it, would be great.

Comment: Created a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RctL3/) but i have a `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getContext'` error in gauge.min.js line 31.

Comment: I have the same problem. Unfortunately, neither of the below answers, tackle the problem at hand. I have working code when linking to an absolute URL but this breaks when I try to link to a relative URL.

Answer (score 18):

The element that you apply the Gauge effect on needs to be a `canvas` element, not a `div`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/RctL3/1/

One has to admit that this is only mentioned in a subordinate clause in the docs:

> The Gauge class handles drawing on canvas and starts the animation.

Comment: How do I copy it all out of jsfiddle?

Comment: You copy the HTML part into your HTML and the JS part into your JS?

Comment: how do I add that JS? I'm a complete noob! In the <head>?

Comment: m90 - Could you write me the whole example? Linking the external scripts? Would help greatly.

Comment: @m90  But how to show the text between the Guage..! its not showing for me.. :(

Answer (score 6):

Change your `<div id="foo">` into a `<canvas id="foo">` and it will work just fine.